# Does the directional derivative exists in all directions?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the function:
$$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \sin \left(y^{2} / x\right) & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text { if } x=0
\end{array}\right.$$

I am trying to find the Directional derivative at $(0,0)$ in the direction of a unit vector $\hat{u}=a\vec{i}+b\vec{j}$. We have:
$$D_u(f)_{(0,0)}=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(at, b t)-f(00)}{t}$$
So we get
$$D_u(f)_{(0,0)}=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{|t| \sin \left(\frac{b^{2} t}{a}\right)}{t}$$

Now for all $a\ne 0$, since the sine term goes to zero, we get $D_u(f)=0$.
But when $a=0$? Is it possible to find the directional derivative?

Comment: When $a=0$, what is the definition of $f(0,bt)$?

Comment: Yes i got it now Thanks